# React CDN based page not working with Babel 6.1.19

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following React code works when the Babel-Core CDN is changed to version 5.8.24 but not when the version is 6.1.19 as included. I am heavily confused as to why this would matter? Shouldn't things be forward-compatible? Or am I just missing something really obvious here?

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-
core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        const HelloMessage = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, 
document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

Check the `babel-standalone` [DOC](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone).

Check the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app"></div>
           <script type="text/babel">
              const HelloMessage = React.createClass({
                 render: function() {
                     return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
                 }
              });

              ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, 
                  document.getElementById('app'));
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Standalone build of Babel for use in non-Node.js environments, It's bundled with all the standard Babel plugins and presets.