# How would I properly use React.js CDN in PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, cdn

How would I properly use React.js CDN in PHP file?  With my code below, I can successfully display `hey` on the browser.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        class Temp extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h1>hey</h1>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<Temp />, document.getElementById("app"));
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this time, I want this to be displayed via another js file: `Temp.js`.  My attempt below isn't showing anything on the browser.  I feel like I'm making a tiny mistake but can't spot it.

I'm totally aware on how `create-react-app` works, I'm just trying to dabble with the CDNs and see how it works.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `Temp.js`:

```
var Temp = React.createClass({

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        term: 'test'
    };
};

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.term}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Temp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: How is your Temp.js file included?

Comment: @khartnett If I include `src="./Temp.js"` in `<script type="text/jsx" src="./Temp.js"></script>`, then nothing will show up in the browser.  I had to get rid of `src="./Temp.js"`

Comment: @khartnett in other words, I gotta use `src="./Temp.js"` the correct way

Comment: `<script type="text/jsx" src="Temp.js"></script>` works fine for me. Also, this is in now shape or form a PHP question.

Comment: @ChrisG not sure why it isn't working me.  Am I missing something trivial that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I was getting React.createClass is not a function with the Temp.js you have, but if you use the same JSX it should work. Also needed to close the <?php tag

Comment: When you look at the source (Ctrl+U) and click on the underlined `src` attribute of the script, do you see your Temp.js content? Did you check the browser for error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with importing react via cdn but I was able to get it working by replacing the CDN you had with

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js">  </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

Source: [React CDN based page not working with Babel 6.1.19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117408/react-cdn-based-page-not-working-with-babel-6-1-19)

Probably something to do with using a dev version of react?

Comment: ugh, still not working for me.  I'm not sure if I'm missing anything trivial based on my original post

Comment: what browser? could be a cache issue at this point. if your in chrome try ctrl + f5 to clear the page cache and then use ctrl + shift + i and see if there are any console errors

Comment: I figured it out!  I wrote my file path wrong.  I have another question though, how come I can't use `this.state.term` in my js file?  I've updated it in my original post for you to check it out.  If I do something as simple is `<h1>hey</h1>` like before, then it displays fine.  But why can't I display states?

Comment: You are using react.createClass (es5) syntax but trying to set state via es6. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526493/react-createclass-vs-extends-component